# How do I push my code with pycharm to a server when it fails?

Tags: pycharm

I want to push my code to a server with pycharm but I get the following error:

```
[11/7/20, 12:19 PM] Upload to cc
[11/7/20, 12:19 PM] Upload file '/Users/brando/ultimate-utils/python_pg.py' to '/home/miranda9/ultimate-utils/python_pg.py'
[11/7/20, 12:19 PM] Failed to transfer file '/Users/brando/ultimate-utils/python_pg.py': could not close the output stream for file "sftp://cc-login.campuscluster.illinois.edu/ultimate-utils/python_pg.py".
```

how do I figure out how to fix the issue? e.g. perhaps a good start would be for me to identify what is causing the issue. How do I do that?

---

Other things I've tried:

I tried checking with the configuration option to see if my connection works and it does:

[image]

Although it **DID** connect according to my screenshot, it fails to do the push...but even though it connects I tried switching from SFTP to the other two options to FTP and FTPS. Those never actually even manage to connect. I changed the port from 21 to 22 there since in 22 it did work with SFTP but it didn't work.

An example screen shot:

[image]

any help? what might be causing the issue? Why does the push from save does not work but testing the connection DOES work in sftp. Any ideas to test what is going on would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This might be too late for you, but I had the same issue. At least for me, the deployment server's disk was full. If you free up some space, it should be able to successfully deploy the file.

Comment: for me if I remember correctly, the specific cluster I was pushing has a specific address for pushing data (including code). So I think I changed the info in pycharm to push there on save. Thanks though! Good to know that can be an issue. Pitty you didn't get a better error to figure out that issue.